# floatingStyles are missing in the result of useFloating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tooltip, floating-ui

i am using  "@floating-ui/react": "^0.25.4" and when calling `useFloating` hook i dont get `floatingStyles` property/field in the result of the hook call (even though it is not marked as optional in types). The field not only is undefined it just does not exist.
I am assuming it is a bug in the library. Any workarounds ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I even could not reproduce it in pristine environments, so it's clearly something tied to my application.

Thing is, *what?*

All I know is that I've been transiting between different versions of `@floating-ui` quite a bunch. So I had this epiphany of maybe a conflict and... yes, it was!

What worked for me was deleting my `node_modules` folder and `npm install` again.